# Check that an input is in a certain format

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am trying to create a regex that checks that an input is in the following formats:

```
% word word number # % word word number #     - OK
% word word # % word word #    - OK
% word word word # % word word #    - OK
% # %% word word #    - NOT OK
```

So between `%` and `#` there can be between 1-8 `word`, and only 1 or none `number`, number must also be at the end.
I don't mind about spaces between the symbols and the text, or numbers, just the words between, so
`%word word#%word word#` or `%word word number#%word word#` is accepted but `%wordword#%wordword#` or `%wordwordnumber#%wordwordnumber#` is not okay.
Feel free to ask me anything .

Comment: Please add the regular expression you tried with? Which characters are allowed in a "word"? Are negative, fractional numbers allowed, or in scientific notation, or hex, ... Can a fractional number start with the decimal point. Thousands separators? Capitals? Accented letters? Greek, Arabic, ... I think we can safely say this question lacks some essential ingredients.

Comment: By word I only mean english capital, or lower case characters, no symbols whatsoever.

Comment: Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/1XDhHy/1)?

Comment: Yes, thanks, thats almost what I wanted I'll made a slight modification myself from there `%wordword#%wordword#` is not okay while in your case it is, I'll just remove the /s

Comment: But how would you distinguish `wordword` from just `word`. I mean: 'playalong' could be interpreted as one, two, three, ... words, depending on what? Is it not just one word when there are no spaces in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this regular expression, with `i` modifier to make it case-insensitive:

[^(%(\s*[a-z]+){1,8}\s*\d*\s*#\s*){2}$](https://regex101.com/r/1XDhHy/2)

NB: The difference between `wordword` and `word word` is superfluous: unless there is some rule to determine when a word ends other than the occurrence of a non-letter (like a space), `wordword` is just a long `word`. The `[a-z]+` pattern will just grab all of it in one go.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and is a valid point, its just that in my case i dont mind, cause `word` will be a specific string and I'll know if its not correct

Comment: So in your case `word word word` would be really a repetition of the *same* word?

Comment: No, word, will be an string in an array of strings

Comment: In that case use `(word1|word2|word3)` (taken from the array) to match the first word, and then use `\1` to repeat that pattern for any other occurrences.